# php cant find class if file name starts with a capital B

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with this very confusing error. I have a class and an extended class. If my extended file name starts with a capital B then it cannot find my database class. If I name anything else, literally anything else it works.

My database class looks like so

```
class Database
{
    public $db;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        if (DATABASE == true) 
        {
            $this->db = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
            if ($this->db->connect_error) 
            {
                exit('Some of the database login credentials seem to be wrong.' . '-' .  $this->db->connect_error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my extended class is like so

```
class BlogModel extends Database
{
    public function getBlogPosts()
    {
        $query = array();
        if ($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM blog')) 
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $query[] = $row;
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        return $query;
        $mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

The filename BlogModel.php causes the error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in C:\wamp\www\website\app\model\BlogModel.php on line 4
```

If I change it to blogModel.php it works. I don't mind just changing the filename but in the interest of understanding and learning I'd like to know why this is happening.

Edit:
This is how I include the files

```
define('ROOT', str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
define('HOST', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);              
define('URL', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);             
define('APP', ROOT . '/app/');  
define('MODEL', ROOT . '/app/model/');                     
define('VIEW', APP . '/view/'); 
define('CONTROLLER', ROOT . '/app/controller/');   
$models = array_diff(scandir(MODEL), array('.', '..'));
foreach ($models as $m) 
{
    require_once MODEL . $m;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't really tell us anything, how are you including the files? with an autoloader, for example?  If so that is most likely where the issue lies.

Comment: Inconsistency's in programming don't happen. Show us how you include the files

Comment: I think so titlle doesn't match the content of the question

Comment: the include code of files is need here?

Comment: MODEL string  has directory saperator "/" or "\" at last?

Comment: Wow I guess I suck at asking questions efficiently. I edited to include the code where files are included

Comment: @badsyntax Perhaps you should be using `__autoload()` or preferred `spl_autoload_register()`

Comment: What is the name of the file, is the case proper, such as `BlogModel.php` vs `blogModel.php`. linux is case sensitive.  Or `Database` vs `database.php` because its `Database.php` that is not loading.

Comment: I looked at spl_autoload_register. I thought _autoload() was deprecated. It was beyond me Im still trying to understand it. This project is me just trying to learn. Perhaps Im trying something too advanced for my level?

Comment: No, to use PSR autoloader, you should understand how namespaces work first.  What you have is ok, but in-efficient.  The PSR ( spl_autoload ) generally will use the Namespace as the file path.  So you might have a `namespace App;` class `Database` and then the file will be in `App/Database.php`. its more efficient because you only load what you need when you need it.  And the namespace tells where it is instead of looping over the entire directory.

Comment: the files are proper case. but it seems to be any capital B. If I name it foo.php or Foo.php or bar.php it works. If I name it Bar.php it does not.

Comment: Can you put the actual path to both of those files? such as `app/database.php`  its not the blog class that is not loading its the extended database class  `Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found`

Comment: the path is like so site.com/app/model/Database.php and site.com/app/model/BlogModel.php

Comment: Oh, I got it!.  Alphabetical order your loading them alphabetically with scandir.  So BlogModel, loads before Database, and because it requires it, it immediately tries to load the file ( when included ), but the loading function hasn't processed that far.  Or that is my best guess, at least.  Casing may be sorted differently, but Id have to check on that.

Comment: You could test this by naming `BlogModel.php` as `ABlogModel.php` and see if you get same error.  Even using `CBlogModel.php` should fail anything before `Database` alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an autoloader that is PSR compliant you would need to restructure your directory tree.

The code I use is a (not fully) PSR-4 compliant code:

```
<?php
    #cn is class name
    #fn is file name
    #ns is namespace
    #np is namespace pointer

    class Loader{
        public function load($class){
            $cn = ltrim($class, '\\');
            $fn = '';
            $ns = '';

            if($np = strrpos($cn, '\\')){
                $ns = substr($cn, 0, $np);
                $cn = substr($cn, $np + 1);
                $fn = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $ns) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            }

            require ($fn .= strtolower(str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $cn)) . '.php');
        }

        public function __construct(){
            spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
        }
    }

    new Loader;

?>
```

It will load files in a lower case filename, if you do not use namespaces it will attempt to load from the document root if the object does not exist.

If you are using namespaces, aka:

```
$var = new \path\to\ObjeCt();
```

It would attempt to load `object.php` from `webroot\path\to\`

How one would use this is simple, just include this file and the next time you create an object keep the namespace valid to the path.

Comment: this is not entirely correct, if you have an auto loader you can register  namespace, path pairs then you can do them without namespaces.  An example is on my git hub, ( warning my framework is in the early stages ) but the autoloader works.  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/EVO/Autoloader.php  and can be used like this `EVO_Autoloader::getInstance()->regesterPath( '', EVO_PATH_BASE, 20 );` with no namespace.  That said it's like 100 time more complex .. lol

Comment: In all honesty, yes. I've stripped most of the code in my answer to a bare minimum (hence the code I'm using) as an autoloader is at the core of a system I refused to use a bloated class that could hurt performance. But in essence, its still complaint even if you don't have the ability to reg**i**ster the namespace ;)

Comment: Ouch that hurt, lol, its not bloated when taken in the context of how my framework is structured.  It's completely event driven, which requires rebasing namespace for separating interdependence..  Granted it's over kill for this question though.

Comment: I think the difference between PSR0 and PSR4 the underlines?  such as  `app/worker_database.php` would be in `app/worker/database.php`.  Honestly I forget though.

Comment: Nothing much has changed, but indeed the underscores I might as well remove it as its almost never used.

Comment: I gave you a +1, because I think the OP's issue is that the files are included alphabetically by scandir.  Which this would solve, and because you seem cool :-D, and not least I'm too lazy to write a simplified autoloader, ha ha.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You spotted it quite well, to think of it I had this issue as well when I was just beginning with PHP. Solved it by the newly added `__autoload()` at the time :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123207/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-artisticphoenix).